# Reassigning unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr, clion

On this code Jetbrains CLion complains that `'unique_ptr::operator=(const unique_ptr &)' is deleted`:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> test;
test = std::make_unique<std::string>();
```

[image: Screenshot]

But on this:

```
auto test2 = std::make_unique<std::string>();
```

there is no complains.

Is CLion right or not? Can one reassign `unique_ptr`?

**upd** It compiles OK by GCC, CLang and MSVC++, and must be compiled by any C++14 compiler. It's just a curiosity about CLion.

Comment: CLion doesn't seem to properly recognize the value category of the expression

Comment: Try **compiling** the code. IDEs are dumb unless backed by an actual compiler, don't listen to them. In this case the error message is completely misleading and **wrong.**

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant it compiles ok, updated the post

Comment: @vladon then it's an IDE bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is fine, it should compile (and it indeed does); this is [a bug in the IDE](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4690).

The error message about the copy assignment operator is completely misleading; while the copy assignment operator **is** deleted, the move assignment operator is not, and in this case, it will be invoked, since `make_unique()` returns a `unique_ptr` by value, and that's an rvalue.

Comment: Isn't it even possible for the assignment to be optimized out? I.e. there's technically no need for the move assignment operator either, depending on the compiler.

Comment: @user673679 it can be optimized out; however, that's an implementation detail and should not be the reason why the code does or does not compile.